# MonoTouch: Can't create PSTitleValueSpecifier

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, settings, monodevelop, title

I'm trying to create a `PSTitleValueSpecifier` in my settings bundle but it never appears when I run the app and look in the settings. According to the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSTitleValueSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007015-SW1) it needs something called `DefaultValue` but I can't create this in MonoDevelop as every time I type `DefaultValue` it changes to another setting, such as Autocorrection for example.

I've tried adding every key that it will allow me to and I still can't get this displaying. The rest of the settings are working fine (I have 2 textfields). Is this a known issue or has something changed with the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I opened my plist file using Xcode and was able to set the default value here. This did the trick, I can now see my PSTitleValueSpecifier in Settings.